# Large bit arrays in C

Tags: c, linux, bitarray

Our OS professor mentioned that for assigning a process id to a new process, the kernel incrementally searches for the first zero bit in a array of size equivalent to the maximum number of processes(~32,768 by default), where an allocated process id has 1 stored in it.

As far as I know, there is no bit data type in C. Obviously, there's something I'm missing here.

Is there any such special construct from which we can build up a bit array? How is this done exactly?

More importantly, what are the operations that can be performed on such an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `struct` can assign members bit-sizes, but that's the extent of a "bit-type" in 'C'.

```
struct int_sized_struct {
   int foo:4;
   int bar:4;
   int baz:24;
};
```

The rest of it is done with bitwise operations.  For example. searching that PID bitmap can be done with:

```
extern uint32_t *process_bitmap;
uint32_t *p = process_bitmap;
uint32_t bit_offset = 0;
uint32_t bit_test;

/* Scan pid bitmap 32 entries per cycle. */
while ((*p & 0xffffffff) == 0xffffffff) {
  p++;
}

/* Scan the 32-bit int block that has an open slot for the open PID */
bit_test = 0x80000000;
while ((*p & bit_test) == bit_test) {
   bit_test >>= 1;
   bit_offset++;
}
pid = (p - process_bitmap)*8 + bit_offset;
```

This is roughly 32x faster than doing a simple for loop scanning an array with one byte per PID.  (Actually, greater than 32x since more of the bitmap is will stay in CPU cache.)

Answer (score 4):

Bit arrays are simply byte arrays where you use [bitwise operators](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html) to read the individual bits.

Suppose you have a 1-byte `char` variable. This contains 8 bits. You can test if the lowest bit is true by performing a bitwise AND operation with the value 1, e.g.

```
 char a = /*something*/;
 if (a & 1) {
    /* lowest bit is true */
 }
```

Notice that this is a *single* ampersand. It is completely different from the *logical* AND operator `&&`. This works because `a & 1` will "mask out" all bits except the first, and so `a & 1` will be nonzero if and only if the lowest bit of `a` is 1. Similarly, you can check if the second lowest bit is true by ANDing it with 2, and the third by ANDing with 4, etc, for continuing powers of two.

So a 32,768-element bit array would be represented as a 4096-element *byte* array, where the first byte holds bits 0-7, the second byte holds bits 8-15, etc. To perform the check, the code would select the byte from the array containing the bit that it wanted to check, and then use a bitwise operation to read the bit value from the byte.

As far as what the operations are, like any other data type, you can read values and write values. I explained how to read values above, and I'll explain how to write values below, but if you're really interested in understanding bitwise operations, read the link I provided in the first sentence.

How you write a bit depends on if you want to write a 0 or a 1. To write a 1-bit into a byte `a`, you perform the opposite of an AND operation: an OR operation, e.g.

```
 char a = /*something*/;
 a = a | 1; /* or a |= 1 */
```

After this, the lowest bit of `a` will be set to 1 whether it was set before or not. Again, you could write this into the second position by replacing 1 with 2, or into the third with 4, and so on for powers of two.

Finally, to write a zero bit, you AND with the *inverse* of the position you want to write to, e.g.

```
 char a = /*something*/;
 a = a & ~1; /* or a &= ~1 */
```

Now, the lowest bit of `a` is set to 0, regardless of its previous value. This works because `~1` will have all bits *other than* the lowest set to 1, and the lowest set to zero. This "masks out" the lowest bit to zero, and leaves the remaining bits of `a` alone.

Comment: but, if you use the char to mimic a bit array, don't all the operations on it (such as &2,&4...) sound too cryptic?

Comment: It's only cryptic if you don't understand bitwise operations, much like any programming language or language feature is cryptic if you don't understand it. It's generally advised not to try to be clever and use bit-fiddling tricks to replace regular arithmetic for reasons of clarity, but when you're talking about getting and setting individual bits, bitwise operations are the *only* way to do it. You can wrap the operations in functions or macros if you think it makes the code more readable, but at some level you will have to use bitwise operations to manipulate bits. That's what they're for.

Comment: Maybe cryptic if your are not used to it but it's fast ! And you can search for the first zero bit by looking at 32 bits at each step if your bit array is actually an int array.

Comment: Some CPU architectures have an instruction for finding the first zero bit in sequential memory locations, as well as finding the first clear bit or set bit in a CPU register.  In the old days, data structures were often optimized for such architectural features.  Linux chooses to be more CPU neutral for practical reasons, like supporting a wide range of CPU architectures and simplifying the source code.

Comment: It's not cryptic if you write the (insanely trivial) macros to do the bit manipulation, and then use those macros to access the bit array.

Answer (score 1):

see http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Answer (score 0):

No bit type in C, but bit manipulation is fairly straight forward.  Some processors have bit specific instructions which the code below would nicely optimize for, even without that should be pretty fast.  May or may not be faster using an array of 32 bit words instead of bytes.  Inlining instead of functions would also help performance.

If you have the memory to burn just use a whole byte to store one bit (or whole 32 bit number, etc) greatly improve performance at the cost of memory used.

```
unsigned char data[SIZE];

unsigned char get_bit ( unsigned int offset )
{
    //TODO: limit check offset
    if(data[offset>>3]&(1<<(offset&7))) return(1);
    else return(0);
}
void set_bit ( unsigned int offset, unsigned char bit )
{
    //TODO: limit check offset
    if(bit) data[offset>>3]|=1<<(offset&7);
    else    data[offset>>3]&=~(1<<(offset&7));
}
```

Comment: Imagine using a 32,768-byte (32KB) array for just the process ids! Are you sure there's a performance jump in using such a scheme?